# Does using yellow paper hide the yellow tracking dots that commercial printers put on anything you print?

Tags: consumer-products, government, electronics

I just learned about those yellow dots printers put on paper that the government uses to track you in case it doesn't like what you're printing. Does anyone know if using yellow paper like [this](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/17767367067481397343) in order to prevent the tracking dots from being visible enough to track you works? I was surprised I couldn't find a clear answer to this anywhere else, so if I'm in the wrong place please direct me to the right one. I already tried [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/8031/does-using-yellow-paper-hide-the-yellow-tracking-dots-that-commercial-printers-p).

Comment: Where have you learned this from, can you add a link into your question, please?

Comment: To post a question here you must give some sort of reference to a "claim".

Comment: You're apparently referring to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Identification_Code

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users)According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you *hear or read*. This question appears to be *your own* speculation, and is off-topic. Please edit it to reference a claim that other people are making and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).

Comment: (To be clear: The existence of MIC isn't your speculation. The idea that yellow paper will prevent it is. Also, the phrase "track you" is a bit vague.)

Comment: Some version of this question would probably fit better on Security.SE. Perhaps as a broader question about what methods could be useful to circumvent this.